# Cannot get the multiple channel values in go routines

Tags: go, channel

I have written 2 goroutines for web socket read and write the message. For Example,

```
ch := make(chan bool)
folderName := make(chan string)

go func(co *websocket.Conn) {
    m, d, err := co.ReadMessage()
    fmt.Println(m, string(d), err)

    folderName <- string(d)
    ch <- true

    if string(d) == "closed" {
        ch <- true
        co.Close()
    }
}(conn)
```

This goroutine is used to read the message from the socket and update the channels.

```
go func(co *websocket.Conn) {
    value := <-ch
    fldr := <-folderName

    fmt.Println(fldr, value)
}(conn)
```

This goroutine is for writing the message. But I couldn't get folderName and ch channel values. I don't know how to find the issues.

If I pass the single channel, I can get a message from the channel. But I need to get 2 values in that goroutine.

Could anyone help to resolve the issues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. you cannot send `true` through `ch` which is `chan string`. please edit the code. 2. order matters. Your code that tries to receive must receive `folderName` first, since you send through `folderName` first, otherwise both gorotine will block. 3. Instead of using multiple channels, you can pack your data into a struct and have a single channel, which usually reduce confusion.

Comment: I would also appreciate it if you would accept the answer if it has served the purpose :)

Answer (score 3):

In your case since your reading a single message from the `websocket.Connection` you need to change the sequence in which you read from the channels since your channels are unbuffered your writes will be blocked as longs as there are no consumers and vice versa.
In your case, you write to the `folderName` channel in the first goroutine and then read from the other channel `ch` so both of your goroutines will be blocked.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan bool)
    folderName := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        ch <- true
        folderName <- "Some text"

        .
                .
                .
    }()

    go func() {
        value := <-ch
        fldr := <-folderName

        fmt.Println(fldr, value)
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/rQr5Y2rnXUL)

Comment: Hey, you never hit the `if "Some text" == "closed"` block. As soon as `ch` and `folderName`  channels get their value, the other goroutine resume and prints the value. 
I just thought to give you guys some heads up. The motive of the answer is surely served; if we modify the code so that if block works, but then again a problem will arise that we are closing the channel `close(folderName)` but inside the other goroutine we are (receiving) `<-folderName` it, which might result in deadlock. So, be careful.